# MATLAB Execution Time Increasing

Tags: matlab, optimization

Here is my code. The intent is I have a Wireshark capture saved to a particularly formatted text file. The MATLAB code is supposed to go through the Packets, dissect them for different protocols, and then make tables based on those protocols. I currently have this programmed for ETHERNET/IP/UDP/MODBUS. In this case, it creates a column in MBTable each time it encounters a new register value, and each time it comes across a change to that register value, it updates the value in that line of the table. The first column of MBTable is time, the registers start with the second column.

MBTable is preallocated to over 100,000 Rows (nol is very large), 10 columns before this code is executed. The actual data from a file I'm pulling into the table gets to about 10,000 rows and 4 columns and the code execution is so slow I have to stop it. The tic/toc value is calculated every 1000 rows and continues to increase exponentially with every iteration. It is a large loop, but I can't see where anything is growing in such a way that it would cause it to run slower with each iteration.

All variables get initialized up top (left out to lessen amount of code.
The variables eth, eth.ip, eth.ip.udp, and eth.ip.udp.modbus are all of type struct as is eth.header and eth.ip.header. WSID is a file ID from a .txt file opened earlier.

```
MBTable = zeros(nol,10);
tval = tic;
while not(feof(WSID))
    packline = packline + 1;
    fl = fl + 1;

    %Get the next line from the file
    MBLine = fgetl(WSID);
    %Make sure line is not blank or short
    if length(MBLine) >= 3
        %Split the line into 1. Line no, 2. Data, 3. ASCII
        %MBAll = strsplit(MBLine,' ');
        %First line of new packet, if headers included
        if strcmp(MBLine(1:3),'No.')
            newpack = true;
            newtime = false;
            newdata = false;
            stoppack = false;
            packline = 1;
        end
        %If packet has headers, 2nd line contains timestamp
        if newpack
            Ordered = false;
            if packline == 2;
                newtime = true;
                %MBstrs = strsplit(MBAll{2},' ');
                packno = int32(str2double(MBLine(1:8)));
                t = str2double(MBLine(9:20));

                et = t - lastt;
                if lastt > 0 && et > 0
                    L = L + 1;
                    MBTable(L,1) = t;
                end
                %newpack = false;
            end
            if packline > 3              
                    dataline = int16(str2double(MBLine(1:4)));
                    packdata = strcat(packdata,MBLine(7:53));
            end
        end

    else
        %if t >= st

        if packline > 3
            stoppack = true;
            newpack = false;
        end
        if stoppack
            invalid = false;
            %eth = struct;

            eth.pack = packdata(~isspace(packdata));
            eth.length = length(eth.pack);

            %Dissect the packet data
            eth.stbyte = 1;
            eth.ebyte = eth.length;
            eth.header.stbyte = 1;
            eth.header.ebyte = 28;
            %Ethernet Packet Data
            eth.header.pack = eth.pack(eth.stbyte:eth.stbyte+27);
            eth.header.dest = eth.header.pack(eth.header.stbyte:eth.header.stbyte + 11);
            eth.header.src = eth.header.pack(eth.header.stbyte + 12:eth.header.stbyte + 23);
            eth.typecode = eth.header.pack(eth.header.stbyte + 24:eth.header.ebyte);

            if strcmp(eth.typecode,'0800')

                eth.type = 'IP';
                %eth.ip = struct;
                %IP Packet Data
                eth.ip.stbyte = eth.header.ebyte + 1;
                eth.ip.ver = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte);
                %IP Header length
                eth.ip.header.length = 4*int8(str2double(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+1)));
                eth.ip.header.ebyte = eth.ip.stbyte + eth.ip.header.length - 1;
                %Differentiated Services Field
                eth.ip.DSF = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte + 2:eth.ip.stbyte + 3);
                %Total IP Packet Length
                eth.ip.length = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+4:eth.ip.stbyte+7));
                eth.ip.ebyte = eth.ip.stbyte + max(eth.ip.length,46) - 1;
                eth.ip.pack = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte:eth.ip.ebyte);
                eth.ip.ID = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+8:eth.ip.stbyte+11);
                eth.ip.flags = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+12:eth.ip.stbyte+13);
                eth.ip.fragoff = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+14:eth.ip.stbyte+15);
                %Time to Live
                eth.ip.ttl = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+16:eth.ip.stbyte+17));
                eth.ip.typecode = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+18:eth.ip.stbyte+19);
                eth.ip.checksum = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+20:eth.ip.stbyte+23);

                %eth.ip.src = eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+24:eth.ip.stbyte+31);

                eth.ip.src = ...
                    [num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+24:eth.ip.stbyte+25))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+26:eth.ip.stbyte+27))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+28:eth.ip.stbyte+29))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+30:eth.ip.stbyte+31)))];

                eth.ip.dest = ...
                    [num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+32:eth.ip.stbyte+33))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+34:eth.ip.stbyte+35))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+36:eth.ip.stbyte+37))),'.', ...
                    num2str(hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.stbyte+38:eth.ip.stbyte+39)))];

                if strcmp(eth.ip.typecode,'11')
                    eth.ip.type = 'UDP';

                    eth.ip.udp.stbyte = eth.ip.stbyte + 40;
                    eth.ip.udp.src = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.stbyte:eth.ip.udp.stbyte + 3));
                    eth.ip.udp.dest = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.stbyte+4:eth.ip.udp.stbyte+7));
                    eth.ip.udp.length = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.stbyte+8:eth.ip.udp.stbyte+11));
                    eth.ip.udp.checksum = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.stbyte+12:eth.ip.udp.stbyte+15);
                    eth.ip.udp.protoID = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.stbyte+20:eth.ip.udp.stbyte+23);

                    if strcmp(eth.ip.udp.protoID,'0000')
                       eth.ip.udp.proto = 'MODBUS';

                       %eth.ip.udp.modbus = struct;
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte = eth.ip.udp.stbyte+16;
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.transID = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+3);
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.protoID = eth.ip.udp.protoID;
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.length = int16(str2double(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 8:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 11)));
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.UID = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 12:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 13);
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.func = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 14:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+15));
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.register = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 16: eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+19);
                       %Number of words to a register, or the number of registers
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.words = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+20:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+23));
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.bytes = hex2dec(eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+24:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte+25));
                       eth.ip.udp.modbus.data = eth.pack(eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 26:eth.ip.udp.modbus.stbyte + 26 + 2*eth.ip.udp.modbus.bytes - 1);


                       %If func 16 or 23, loop through data/registers and add to table
                       if eth.ip.udp.modbus.func == 16 || eth.ip.udp.modbus.func == 23
                           stp = eth.ip.udp.modbus.bytes*2/eth.ip.udp.modbus.words;
                           for n = 1:stp:eth.ip.udp.modbus.bytes*2;
                              %Check for existence of register as a key?
                              if ~isKey(MBMap,eth.ip.udp.modbus.register)
                                MBCol = MBCol + 1;
                                MBMap(eth.ip.udp.modbus.register) = MBCol; 
                              end
                              MBTable(L,MBCol) = hex2dec(eth.ip.udp.modbus.data(n:n+stp-1));
                              eth.ip.udp.modbus.register = dec2hex(hex2dec(eth.ip.udp.modbus.register)+1);
                           end
                           lastt = t;
                       end

                       %If func 4, make sure it is the response, then put
                       %data into table for register column

                    elseif false

                        %need code to handle serial to UDP conversion box

                    else
                        invalid = true;
                    end

                else
                    invalid = true;
                end

            else
                invalid = true;
            end


            if ~invalid

            end
        end
        %end
    end
   %Display Progress
   if int64(fl/1000)*1000 == fl
       for x = 1:length(mess);
           fprintf('\b');
       end
       %fprintf('Lines parsed: %i',fl);
        mess = sprintf('Lines parsed: %i / %i',fl,nol);
        fprintf('%s',mess);
       %Check execution time - getting slower:
       %%{
       ext = toc(tval);
        mess = sprintf('\nExecution Time: %f\n',ext);
        fprintf('%s',mess);
       %%}
   end
end
ext = toc - exst;
```

Update: I updated my code above to remove the overloaded operators (disp and lt were replaced with mess and lastt)

Was asked to use the profiler, so I limited to 2000 lines in the table (added && L >=2000 to the while loop) to limit the execution time, and here are the top results from the profiler:

```
SGAS_Wireshark_Parser_v0p7_fulleth        1    57.110 s     9.714 s
Strcat                                 9187    29.271 s    13.598 s
Blanks                                 9187    15.673 s    15.673 s
Uigetfile                                 1    12.226 s     0.009 s
uitools\private\uigetputfile_helper       1    12.212 s     0.031 s
FileChooser.FileChooser>FileChooser.show    1  12.085 s      0.006s
...er>FileChooser.showPeerAndBlockMATLAB    1  12.056 s      0.001s
...nChooser>FileOpenChooser.doShowDialog    1  12.049 s    12.049 s
hex2dec                               44924     2.944 s     2.702 s
num2str                               16336     1.139 s     0.550 s
str2double                            17356     1.025 s     1.025 s
int2str                               16336     0.589 s     0.589 s
fgetl                                 17356     0.488 s     0.488 s
dec2hex                                6126     0.304 s     0.304 s
fliplr                                44924     0.242 s     0.242 s
```

It appears to be strcat calls that are doing it. I only explicitly call strcat on one line. Are some of the other string manipulations I'm doing calling strcat indirectly? 
Each loop should be calling strcat the same number of times though, so I still don't understand why it takes longer and longer the more it runs...

also, hex2dec is called a lot, but is not really affecting the time.

But anyway, are there any other methods I can use the combine the strings?

Comment: A few things to note 1)`lt` and `disp` are reserved words. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lt.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html Overloading definitely slows your code down. 2)`CTRL+R` and `CTRL+T` helps you comment/uncomment a line or selected block (with a space after `%`) 3)`MBTable` is initialized as `nol x 10`. Is it possible you write more than `10` elements in a row? Then the initialization fails. 4)You can run profiler to see which lines are slow http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html#f9-17126

Comment: You can take a complete run with a shorter text file, and post the profiler result here. Lines which consumes lots of time are most interested.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, Yvon. Removing the overloaded operators made it start faster, but it still slows down a lot each iteration. As I stated above, the file I'm testing on only writes to 4 of the 10 columns, so that's not the issue. I am going to try the profiler as you suggested...

Comment: I ran the profile and posted the results in my question above. I'm still not sure what to do.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/292870  `strcat` has been reported to be slow. Could you change `strcat(packdata,MBLine(7:53));` to `sprintf('%s%s', packdata, MBLine(7:53));` and see the time changes? Please correct the code if it raises any error, since I'm not sure about the actual data you have in the two variables.

Comment: Also `Blanks` consumes lots of time. I'm surprised blank/commented lines can be so influential. Is it possible you _remove_ all your comments (maybe after a backup, just an experiment) and run another profile? Really not sure why this happens.

Comment: Yvon, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! It's not exactly what you have, so I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue:

The string (an char array in MATLAB) packdata was being resized and reallocated over and over again. That's what was slowing down this code. I did the following steps:

I eliminated the redundant variable packdata and now only use eth.pack.

I preallocated eth.pack and a couple "helper variables" of known lengths by running blanks ONCE for each before the loop ever starts

```
eth.pack = blanks(604);
thisline = blanks(47);
smline = blanks(32);
```

(Note: 604 is the maximum possible size of packdata based on headers + MODBUS protocol)

Then I created a pointer variable to point to the location of the last char written to packdata.

```
pptr = 1;

...

dataline = int16(str2double(MBLine(1:4)));

thisline = MBLine(7:53); %Always 47 characters

smline = [thisline(~isspace(thisline)),blanks(32-sum(~isspace(thisline)))]; %Always 32 Characters

eth.pack(pptr:pptr+31) = smline;

pptr = pptr + 32;
```

The above was inside the 'if packline > 3' block in place of the 'packdata =' statement, then at the end of the 'if stoppack' block was the reset statement:

```
pptr = 1; %Reset Pointer
```

FYI, not surprisingly this brought out other flaws in my code which I've mostly fixed but still need to finish. Not a big issue now as this loop executes lightning fast with these changes. Thanks to Yvon for helping point me in the right direction.

I kept thinking my huge table, MBTable was the issue... but it had nothing to do with it.